# Is there a way to return the original value in an ifelse function?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have been trying to get my Strength value to increase if the point value increases, but also revert to the starting input if the point value is dropped back down to zero.

This is all I could come up with before I got too frustrated looking for answers elsewhere, and I tried other methods that didn't do what I wanted. This code basically made it so any time the PTS value changed it increased by 1. I want to be able to increase it and have STR reset to the original value if the PTS == 0

```
(function(){
   var STR = this.getField("Str");
   var PTS = this.getField("strpts");

   if (PTS == 0) event.value = STR;
   else if (PTS == 10) event.value = STR + 1;
}())
```

Comment: This logic is inside an IIFE, which would only execute once.  How would this logic repeat?  It's also unclear where `event` is defined.

Comment: I'd guess `event` is plopped on the global

Comment: The code is defined for the text field box of Str, therefore event is for text field the code is for. I'm not sure why it repeats the process. I would change strpts to 10, and then back to 0 and it would continually add +1 to the Str text field (without making it the definitive Str, because I have a separate field that is calculated based on the Str value, and that text field doesn't change. Reminder I'm doing all of this in Adobe Acrobat pro.